# Find Excel Row using Word Macro and Reference Other Cells in that Row

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a Word macro that launches a UserForm.

I am trying to add a feature to update certain fields from an external excel document.
Unfortunately, the Word macro does not recognize many of the Excel VBA commands.

Here is the idea:

1. Search excel spreadsheet for a keyword "Vendor".
2. Determines its row (RowCrnt).
3. Bring the content from a specific column in that row back to the word macro (docField).

Here is where I'm at:

```
Private Sub updateForm_Click()

'Start by parsing the Test Tracking spreadsheet
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim testTrack_File As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RowCrnt As Long

testTrack_File = "FileName.exe"
appExcel.Workbooks.Open testTrack_File

'Search Test Tracking spreadsheet for the Vendor

With appExcel.Sheets("Testing_Queue")

'Code Needed here
 docField = 

End With

appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
appExcel.Quit
Set appExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use MS Excel Functions from within MS Word macros, by way of the `WorksheetFunction` object.  If you know the column in your worksheet that contains your search criteria, then you can use a simple `vlookup`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx

Comment: I sincerely hope that that `FileName.exe` up there is a placeholder text, otherwise, we have to assume you're passing an *executable* to Excel. Nuh uh. Not good. **:D** How about enabling references to the Excel object and using ***early binding***? That can help you out a lot if this is your first foray into inter-application manipulation in MS Office.

Comment: Haha sorry that was supposed to be an xls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use Excel VBA functions in your code -- you can use `.Find` inside your with block, like so:

```
With appExcel.Sheets("Testing_Queue")

    Dim xlCell As Object
    Set xlCell = .Cells.Find("asdf")

    'Get the row where the value was found
    Dim xlRow As Integer
    xlRow = xlCell.Row

    'change the target column to whichever you want
    Dim xlCol As Integer
    xlCol = 6

    Dim targetCellValue
    targetCellValue = .Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value

    MsgBox (targetCellValue)

End With
```